# Are space exploration history questions on topic here?

Tags: discussion, scope

Prompted by Jon Ericson♦ in a comment to [this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/1259/why-did-the-usa-fail-to-be-the-first-rocket-power), I'd like to know if questions on history of space exploration are on-topic here. There's already a History.SE site, but I'm not sure folks there are tech savvy enough to separate the wheat from the chaff.

Answer (score 2):

My own take on the issue is that it is very hard to disentangle politics from tech of space exploration:

- Space law was declared [on-topic](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164/space-law-and-stack-exchange-policy-on-legal-advice) (it is set by politicians/diplomats/lawyers with technical advice)
- Military aspects of space were declared [on-topic](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72/is-military-use-of-space-on-topic-is-weaponry-testing-on-topic) (and we all know war is just politics by other means)

Complex political/technical/economic questions haven't been challenged at all:

- [Why did the Russians never land on the Moon?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/374/why-did-the-russians-never-land-on-the-moon)
- [Why was the NERVA program dropped?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/1145/why-was-the-nerva-program-dropped)
- [What made NASA shut down the Shuttle program?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/1173/what-made-nasa-shut-down-the-shuttle-program)
- [Does any country have real plans for a manned mission to Mars?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/986/does-any-country-have-real-plans-for-a-manned-mission-to-mars)
- [Has any country stated its official position on how it would respond to a discovery of intelligent extra terrestrial life?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/574/has-any-country-stated-its-official-position-on-how-it-would-respond-to-a-discov)
- [How are (robotic) government space exploration missions in Japan initiated?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/484/how-are-robotic-government-space-exploration-missions-in-japan-initiated)
- [What portion of SpaceX's revenue comes from private sources?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/434/what-portion-of-spacexs-revenue-comes-from-private-sources)
- [Is true that Armstrong was not designated as first to walk on the moon?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/1102/is-true-that-armstrong-was-not-designated-as-first-to-walk-on-the-moon)

I can see the danger of **soft** questions that @gerrit alludes to, but it seems we are protected from them by the general rules at StackExchange (**no forum-like banter, no speculative answers**).

Am skeptical that history buffs will be extremely knowledgeable in space history, to be honest.

There's another side of "space history" questions: To gather and maintain popularity, there has to be a wide range of topics accessible to non-professional enthusiasts. For them it may be easier to, say, run through a dozen books on history than to learn anew some real astrodynamics.

Comment: There will always be some interdisciplinarity, but there's another point - same question might attract answers from different perspectives on different sites, on top of different audience. I not only support this @DeerHunter's notion, but also believe it's instrumental to our ability to differentiate ourselves, become a unique and equal entity in the [SE] conglomerate of websites.

Answer (score 0):

If the answer is of *technical* or *scientific* nature: **yes**.

If the answer is of *political* or *economical*, or other *soft* nature: **no**.

Example of *on-topic* historical questions:

- *What power system did the Apollo landers use?*
- *What were the characteristics of the on-board computer systems on the Venera probes?*

Example of *off-topic* historical questions:

- *Why did the USA fail to be the first rocket power?*
- *What caused the Space Race?*

Comment: [Why did the Russians never land on the Moon?](http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/374/why-did-the-russians-never-land-on-the-moon?)

Comment: @DeerHunter, the Russian/moon is Q/A about technical elements driving a political outcome, where USA/Space is political elements driving a technical element. Also in IMHO the USA/space question is overly broad/speculative, and could be just easily be asked for pretty much any industrialized country; why didn't England, France, etc...

Comment: @JamesJenkins - the interaction of politics and technology is much more complicated than you describe. It is almost always about somebody making bad decisions at some stage. A little thought experiment: imagine a question about the Challenger or Columbia accidents. If you restrict yourself to technicalities, sooner or later you are bound to hit the same wall again - because the organizational framework condones and tolerates bad decision-making.

Comment: @DeerHunter, concur.  and I think we all agree that there is some grey line between what is in scope and what is out.  Your USA/Space question seems to be on/near the line.  No offense intending, I just think it is on the wrong side of the line.  Currently those thinking it is on the right side of the line, seem to be in the majority.